# Hortonworks vs Cloudera Architecture Difference

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hadoop2, hortonworks-data-platform

What is the main difference between `HortonWorks` and `Cloudera` ? I see both of them follow the same Architecture.

Comment: This will help you https://www.dezyre.com/article/cloudera-vs-hortonworks-vs-mapr-hadoop-distribution-comparison-/190

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good research, I found that Cloudera and HortonWorks has no difference. They both follow the same Architecture. They take the raw hadoop and do some regressive testing and give an honed product for enterprises. No difference. Just two brands for the same product.

Additionally [this link](https://www.dezyre.com/article/cloudera-vs-hortonworks-vs-mapr-hadoop-distribution-comparison-/190) explains more.